# symmetric multicore processor

Tags: parallel-processing, multicore, smp

For this question,

Consider the following code statements executing at the same time on four processors in a symmetric multicore processor (SMP). Assume that before these statements are executed, both x and y are 0.

Core1:x=2;

Core2:y=2;

Core3:w=x+y+1;

Core4:z=x+y;

What are all the possible resulting values of w, x, y and z? For each possible outcome, explain how you arrived at those values. You will need to examine all possible interleavings of instructions. (9 marks)

Would i be right in thinking that the answer would be:

x = 2, y = 2, w = 1, z = 0

x = 2, y = 2, w = 3, z = 2

x = 2, y = 2, w = 5, z = 4

As the code is executing on a symmetric multicore processor, the processor uses a single address space meaning that if loads and stores are not synchronised, one of the processors could start working on the data before another is finished.

Comment: How should be interpret your answer there? One option per line, so 3 different possibilities? There are more

Comment: I don't know if you're looking for someone to list all possible branches or if you want to understand **more** about concurrent consistency. If the latest, see about [consistency model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model) and [the ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem)